# Connect Qt app to Internet (Symbian)

Tags: qt, symbian

I try to connect to Internet from a Symbian phone (S60v3 FP1) but..not very successfully. When I try the app within the Qt Simulator it works - connects, downloads, etc. Maybe the FP version of the phone is connected with the problem - I've read somewhere that since FP2 there are some changes. 
I have tried to use `QNetworkConfigurationManager` and `QNetworkSession` but again without success. All I want is to see the list with access points on my phone screen (to choose one and the app to run flawlessly) :)

I have included:

```
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
```

I have written the slot:

```
void someApp::replyFinished(QNetworkReply * pReply)
{
    ...nonsense...   
}
```

And from the examples I have read this is needed:

```
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/")));
```

I added (to the .pro file):

`QT += network`

Not sure if it is necessary but this is also in the app:

`MOBILITY = bearer`

What else I need?

I have been using Qt for several days and many things are still unknown to me (..as it is obvious from the whole question).

Thanks for reading (and hopefully helping) :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the NetworkServices capability in the symbian settings in .pro file:

```
symbian: {
...
TARGET.CAPABILITY = "NetworkServices ReadUserData WriteUserData"
...
}
```

This declares that the resulting sis file will want to use networkservices capabilities. I suggest you read up on the symbian capabilities system from forum nokia, as these kinds of problems are quite common.